# How to show a thank you message after someone submits a form in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have made this snippet in Angular: http://plnkr.co/edit/kQz0fiaXLv7T37N8fzJU?p=preview

```
$scope.loadEditForm = function () {
    $scope.checkItem = "yes";
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: 'modalController',
        scope: $scope
    })
    .result.then(function() {
        alert('closed');
    });
};
```

As you can see, I am prompting a "closed" pop-up, but I want to make this much more stylish and show a message IN the modal, instead of having to show an ugly pop-up screen that says "closed".

How could I do this in Angular? Is there some nifty trick?

Comment: You want to show something in the modal which is closing? A common way to show the user something like that is using a notification like [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr), maybe check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `function` defined in your `$scope` to update the value of the `modal's state` and then close it using a `setTimeout`.

You can check my [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mtul6oEJwI05vQVmCVH7?p=preview).

**ModalController**

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('modalController', function($scope) {
    $scope.state = 'open';

    $scope.closeModal = shouldDismiss => {
      $scope.state = shouldDismiss ? 'canceled' : 'closed';

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (shouldDismiss) {
          return $scope.$dismiss();
        }

        $scope.$close();
      }, 500);
    };
});
```

You can change the duration set in the `setTimeout` to display the `modal` longer.

**Main Controller**

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$filter", "$modal", function ($rootScope, $scope, $filter, $modal) {

    $scope.checkItem = "";

    $scope.loadEditForm = function () {
        $scope.checkItem = "yes";
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            controller: 'modalController',
            scope: $scope
        }).result.then();
    };
}]);
```

Adding the `.result.then()` triggers the animation when the `modal` is closing.

Comment: Hi there, 
But it's just shown for 1 second or something and it's gone after that. Thanks anyway, it's certainly better than nothing

Comment: Ah, we are nearly there... could you make it fade or something? Or animate it when it's going to close as well?

Comment: What a hero. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a service and define the following bootstrap modal function. template="url where your modal is present". And display the message using the showThankYouCtrl

```
          $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            template: template,
            size: 'md',
            controller: function ($uibModalInstance) {
              this.data = "Thank you!";
              this.cancel = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
              };
              this.ok = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
              };
            },
            controllerAs: '$showThankYouCtrl'
          });
```